# Sorting algortithm with index in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a set of values for srting algorithm. I have successfully sorted them out. But I also want to have the index for each element after sorting. For example like :

```
Array = [95, 53, 24, 10]
Output after sorting should be like :
10 at index 3, 24 at index 2, 53 at index 1 and 95 at index 0
```

I have used the following logic for sorting. But unable to get the indexes

```
for (int p = 0; p < ((list.size()) - 1); p++) {
    int min = p;                 
    count++;

    for(int q=p+1; q<list.size();q++) {
        if(doubleArray[q] < doubleArray[min]) {
            min = q;
        }
    }

    double smallNumber = doubleArray[p];
    doubleArray[p] = doubleArray[min];
    doubleArray[min] = smallNumber;                  
}
```

Comment: What is your output supposed to be? Do you just want to print to the console? If yes, why not just print the content together with the index in a for-loop?

Comment: google it or follow https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: did I get it right? The problem is to sort the array in **ascending** order (desired result for above `[10, 24, 53, 95]`) *but* you want the output with the original indexes (before sorting)?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept! And welcome to upvote levels ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried the following and it worked.

```
int[] index = {0,1,2,3}
for (int p=0;p<((list.size())-1);p++) 
                 {
                     int min = p;
                     
                     count++;
                     for(int q=p+1; q<list.size();q++) 
                     {
                        if(doubleArray[q]< doubleArray[min])
                        {
                            min = q;
                        }
                     }
                     double smallNumber = doubleArray[p];
                     doubleArray[p] = doubleArray[min];
                     doubleArray[min] = smallNumber;
                     
                     store = index[p];
                     index[p] = index[min];
                     index[min] = store;
                    
                 }
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: Where does 'list' come from?

Comment: Oh Sorry. I haven't explained it. I have a list which I converted into array of double datatype. So that is from where the array is generated.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the point of accepting your own answer when it **still** asks the reader "is this correct"?

Answer (score 4):

As this is probably homework, just some ideas:

- before sorting, create a **copy** of your initial array
- after sorting, iterate the *original* array, and then *find* the index of each value in the *sorted* array, and print that
- the tricky part is dealing with values that show up repeatedly. but that is something that depends on your exact requirements.

Alternatively, you could look into introducing a helpful data structure, such as a `Pair<Integer, Integer>` class. The first entry represents the value, the second one an index. Then you can define your own "sorting" on that class.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to convert the array into an array of pairs, e.g. `[{95, 0}, {53, 1}, {24, 2}, {10, 3}]` and sort that ...

Comment: third option: have a new array with the original indexes that get changed in parallel with the value array (but Stephen's solution is better, less risk of messing it up)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That is just a variation of Stephens idea. Basically you do the mapping in code. I prefer a distinct class instead, too.

Answer (score 2):

As previously suggested, I would also recommend using an additional `Item` class which stores the item on which you want to sort and the initial index:

```
public class Item<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Item<T>> {
    public final T item;
    public final int index;

    public Item(T item, int index) {
        if (item == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("the given item is null!");
        this.item = item;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item<T> t) {
        if (t == null)
            return 1;
        return item.compareTo(t.item);
    }
}
```

When you need to sort the array of doubles, you first create an `ArrayList` containing the `Items` which store the doubles of the input array and the initial index. Since the `Item` class implements the `Comparable` interface, you can use `Collections.sort` for sorting (which will be faster than your bubblesort implementation):

```
public static void sort(Integer... array) {
    List<Item<Integer>> copy = new ArrayList<Item<Integer>>(array.length);

    // copy the input array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        copy.add(new Item<Integer>(array[i], i));


    Collections.sort(copy);

    for (Item<Integer> t : copy)
        System.out.println(t.item + " at index " + t.index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

2. Create a `Pair` class like

`class Pair {
    int val;
    int index;
}`

2. sort it by `valuez`
3. `index` will keep the initial index

Comment: This data structure already exists, there is no need to recreate it. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, only the array exists. But during sorting, values are moved, that's why I suggest creating an additional structure to keep indexes. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The "Pair" data structure is already shipped and can be imported with javafx. Why redo existing classes?

Comment: @TA Thank you for mentioning it. I didn't know that javaFx has such class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below approach:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.SortedSet;
    import java.util.TreeSet;

    public class trial
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    List<Integer> aList = Arrays.asList(95, 53, 24, 10);
    Map<Integer, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<>();

    int index = 0;
    for( Integer aInteger : aList )
    {
      aMap.put(aInteger, index);
      index++;
    }

    SortedSet<Integer> keys = new TreeSet<>(aMap.keySet());

    for( Integer key : keys )
    {
      Integer value = aMap.get(key);
      System.out.println(key + " at index " + value);
     }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you find the old index and shorted value

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> numbers.indexOf(i))).           entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

//output {10=3, 24=2, 53=1, 95=0}